# Laravel email validation rule rfc,dns accepts #@gmail.com

Tags: php, email-validation, laravel-9, laravel-validation

The email validation works with almost every conditions, but it accepts **#@gmail.com** which is an invalid mail. And I also tried 'email' => 'required|email:rfc,dns,filter' still not working. Anyone got solution for this ?

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/

Comment: You can always add a special situation for such cases

Answer (score 0):

For validation of email use the rule [regex](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-regex) like:

`'email' => 'regex:/^.+@.+$/i'`